# Amazon CloudFrount on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I know that i can mount s3 buckets with s3fs on EC2 instance. So i have next question can i  somehow mount Amazon Cloud Front (my S3 buckets files) in EC2 instance?

Comment: You'd mount the actual underlying S3 bucket, not the CloudFront distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe so. Why would you need to do this, though? Cloudfront is merely a CDN front-end to your static data, which is most likely being hosted out of your S3 bucket. There should be no need to interact with the data in Cloudfront other than to expire objects from the cache, which can be done through the Cloudfront API or by setting proper HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFront is a CDN (Content Distribution Network). The source for your CDN (in this case) is your S3 Bucket.

**You can't edit the files that the CDN holds directly**, you must edit their ORIGIN (the file in s3) then you can purge the filename in the CDN so that it will grab the updated file form S3.

It doesn't make any sense to mount files from a CDN, it is only meant for serving files to end users (from one of many possible edge servers where the files are located).